# Instagram API to control iframe embedded video player

Tags: iframe, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

With [YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=de) and [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/api) we can control videos in embedded iframe with the appropriate APIs/SDKs. They provide js objects to call e.g. playVideo() or listen to different events.

Is this possible somehow with Instagram videos too? I couldn't find anything on the [Instagram API page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api).

Actually I want to listen to some "play" and "pause" events, to measure if the user has watched the complete video. Or any other ideas to do that?